# Evaluate the following integral with R its boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

R is the boundary of the rectangle with corners (1,0),(1,1),(-1,1)(-1,0)
How do I evaluate the integral

$L_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{R}\frac{z^n}{z^2+z+1}dz $.
I was thinking by using Cauchy integral Formula, but I couldn't approach anything interesting.

Comment: Do not delete your question after you received an answer. That is unfair to the user answering, whose effort then was wasted.

Comment: Yeah sure I am sorry @DanielFischer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The poles of the integrand are at $z_1=e^{i 2 \pi/3}$ and $z_2=e^{-i 2 \pi/3}$, with only $z_1$ being within $R$.  Thus, by the residue theorem, the integral is simply the residue at $z=z_1$, or

$$-i\frac{e^{i 2 n \pi/3}}{\sqrt{3}}  = \frac1{\sqrt{3}}\left [\sin{\left (\frac{2 n \pi}{3} \right )} - i \cos{\left (\frac{2 n \pi}{3} \right )} \right ]$$

Comment: All too easy ... +1

Comment: @RonGordon Here the computed result is $L_n$ or the integral?

Comment: @user123: $L_n$, but not wrong to call it "the integral" because the integrand includes the $i 2 \pi$ factor.

Comment: I am sorry @RonGordon but I dont really see how you get that result.I know how to calculate the residue but

Comment: @user123: if you know how to compute the residue, then what's the issue?

Comment: @user123: 1) $e^{-i 4 \pi/3} = e^{i 2 \pi/3}$, and 2) complex roots of a quadratic with real coeffs are complex conjugates of each other.  But yes, $z_1$ should be $e^{i 2 \pi/3}$.

Comment: @user123: yes, fixed.